# Cropper.js: No smoothing with zoom?

Tags: cropper, cropperjs

I'm using [Cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) and wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to stop it smoothing out the image when you zoom in. I want it to stay pixelated because I want to use it to crop video game sprite sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually just worked it out. You can add this CSS:

```
img { 
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /*                     */
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox             */
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera               */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and Safari) */
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed       */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                */
    image-rendering: pixelated                  /* Confirmed working in Chrome
    }
```

I found the whole thing minus the last line [here](https://superuser.com/questions/530317/how-to-prevent-chrome-from-blurring-small-images-when-zoomed-in) but it wasn't working on Chrome so I added the last line found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/pixelated) and now it's working.